# Is there any 'automatic' way to translate records from database in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, database, translation, factory

So I need to translate the records from the database, Im searching a way to do this 'automatic' way but I cannot find any solution.
I'm using astrotomic/laravel-translatable and I created a new Provider for the 'Food' in en_US and in hr_HR.
So I seed the database with both en and hr, but they give random stuff where the translations are not correct.
For example.... Food name is 'pasta' in en(english), and 'pasta' in hr(croatian) is 'tjestenina'...
Can i seed the database with just 'pasta' and do some stuff to translate it automatically or I need to do this by hand.
Here's the code....

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use App\Models\Category;


class MealFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        # When installed via composer
        require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

        $en_faker = \Faker\Factory::create('en_US');
        $hr_faker = \Faker\Factory::create('hr_HR');

        $title_en = $en_faker->unique()->food;
        $title_hr = $hr_faker->unique()->food;

        $desc_en = $en_faker->text;
        $desc_hr = $hr_faker->text;


        return [
            'category_id' => rand(null, 5),
            'en' => [
                'title' => $title_en,
                'description' =>  $desc_en
            ],
            'hr' => [
                'title' => $title_hr,
                'description' =>  $desc_hr
            ],
            'status' => 'created'

        ];
    }
}
```

and this is the seeder...

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Meal;
use App\Models\Tag;
use App\Models\Ingredient;


class MealSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Meal::factory()->count(10)->create();

        foreach (Meal::all() as $meal) {
            $tags = Tag::inRandomOrder()->take(rand(1, 8))->pluck('id');
            $ingredients = Ingredient::inRandomOrder()->take(rand(1, 6))->pluck('id');
            $meal->tags()->attach($tags);
            $meal->ingredients()->attach($ingredients);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you reviewed [localization](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization)?

Comment: Yes I did and it only says how to work with the .json files for translation, and it's a manual way with key => value approach.

Comment: There are a few packages that you could use such as [this one](https://github.com/JoggApp/laravel-google-translate) or [this one](https://github.com/JoggApp/laravel-google-translate). You could use them as part of custom artisan commands to pull data and translate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store your translated record on database at all your data is dynamic You can use a third-party api for translation realtime and you may create a Controller for using that translation api and then show it to user.

If your data is static you can also use a translation api on your `seeder`, by reading English words statically from database and translate it to Croatian using api and store it on database

Otherwise you should you need to do it by hand.

In case you are not familiar with using a third-party [this link](https://functional.works-hub.com/learn/integrations-of-third-party-apis-in-laravel-95527) might help you

Comment: I think you are on to something, third-party API is a fine idea, honestly, that did not occur in my mind... I'll try to implement it and comment u back if I succeed.
You gave me a great idea, but I want to store the translated record in the database so I can grab them depending on the language I set on the site.

Comment: Yes you can do that, the only problem is every api i found is paid, but there is some other methods you can use unofficial api for google translate but it's not reliable for realtime translating but it's good for seeding database one time

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just initialize the database with the boostrap English data and write a snippet (probably using a translation library) to translate your English data to Croation (and store it in the correponding database field)?

BTW, it might be better practice to store these data in e.g., POT files (used in Wordpress etc.) for more flexible internationalization (i18n).

Comment: Yeah, I could try that but I think Laravel doesn't support those files and because of that, I need to write my own package or find one that does that for me.
I want to make it using the translatable package I mentioned, those are like prerequisites.